# Convert a number to hh mm ss

Tags: apex

How to convert a number into hh:mm:ss format in apex code??

> example : Integer time = 120;   // in seconds

Answer (score 7):

You can use DateTime to do this:

```
Integer seconds = 120;
System.debug(DateTime.valueOf(seconds*1000).formatGMT('HH:mm:ss'));
```

Output:

> 00:02:00

This works for values less than 24 hours, at which point it would wrap around.

Comment: Why `K` and not `H`?

Comment: @FernandoGavinho Actually, you're right. I did mean HH.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer times = 120;
dateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(0);
system.debug(dt.addseconds(times).formatGMT('HH:mm:ss'));

 // Output :  |DEBUG|00:02:00
```

Comment: It will be nice if you add sample output you got.